# .des files not opening in xcode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I have a problem that i want to open and edit some images of .png extension that are currently in .des extension (for example button_start.png is in the form button_start.des) when i open button_start.des in the xcode it just show a text file like this(button_start.png 12234.00132330122309.that is now of image along with a long numerical number or possibly a hash code) i had been trying to open this .des file with many softwares like coreldraw and quickbooks but it still dont open.It had been weeks but still i am not finding any solution.please guys help me to solve this problem. thanks

Comment: Why don't you rename them to .png? Do you need them like .des files?

Comment: thanks for replying .yeah i need them with .des extension. i want to edit those .des files and then put them back in xcode with .des extension.but i dont know how to edit them.

Answer (score 0):

[`.des`-files are 3D-project-file](http://www.fileinfo.com/extension/des)s. Xcode can't read nor see them, so you need to open them in the application they were created in and export them as PNGs.

If you added the `.des`-ending manually to a `.png`-file, you could simply rename the file `file.png` and it will work.

Comment: .des are not opening with 3d graphics software like coreldraw and or quickbooks.if i just rename them .png to .des xcode throws an exception

Comment: If that's the case, the files are broken or incorrectly stored or has the incorrect error. Try using a service for finding the file type/extension, this for instance: http://www.cometdocs.com/file.htm , or this: http://mark0.net/onlinetrid.aspx .

Comment: thanks for getting back.Basically i am editing graphics of a game in which the ".des" files do not have error they are working fine in the current build.now either i have to edit them (in that case i don know which software to try) or i have to make some .png images and convert them to .des(still i dont know any software that can do that).I have also tried to change .png files to .des with coreldraw but it doesnt work.

Comment: Well, what application are you using to edit the game/what type of game is it? Not everything is port-able to the iOS-platform, unfortunately.

Comment: it is normal 2d game developed for ios and its working fine on the simulator so no question of portability.that games has certain files with .des extension and those files are of graphics.i want to edit those .des files .hope its clear now

Comment: I'm still not sure what you're trying to do - it's pretty clear to me that Xcode can't edit the files, and if the application they were most likely made with won't open them either, they are corrupted. I'm sorry there's nothing else I can do to help you.

Comment: if they are corrupted how would they work fine in the current build.but any way thanks for concern